# Magento 2 Chekout - Inline translate the labels of Ui Components

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, inline-translations

Is there anyway to make the labels of Ui components added to the checkout via layout.xml (static) or LayoutProcessor (dynamic) **inline translatable**?

I tried adding `translate="true"` to the xml element so it'd look like below but it does not work.
`<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label1</item>`

In the LayoutProcessor I changed the `'label' => 'Label1',` to `'label' => __('Label1'),` there's no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are not inline translatable. But can be translated using language .csv files when you add `translate="true"` to the `label` node.